# How to import Java libraries installed in Debian

Tags: debian, java

Commonly, in order to use Apache’s FileUtils in Java, one would add the appropriate `.jar` to the properties.

This does not seem appropriate for Debian as Debian offers the option of installing the Apache Java libraries via repository.

How does one import the libraries intstalled through Aptitude / apt-get. e.g., `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those libraries should be located in `/usr/share/java/`, so you could use this path to add them to your classpath. So for example, if you installed `libcommons-io-java` in version 2.4.5 using apt-get, you should be able to use this library by either adding `/usr/share/java/commons-io.jar` or `/usr/share/java/commons-io-2.4.jar` to your classpath (as far as I know the one without the version should always be the newest installed, while using the file with the included version gives you the guaranty to always have the chosen version).

If you generally want to know where the files from those packages are located, you can go to the [Debian Package Overview](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages), search for your library and look up the file list.

Comment: Thanks, my thought was that Debian installed packages could/should be part of the classpath, but in retrospect that may be Debian-automagicy - but it's not very Javaesque.

Comment: Yeah, I personally would recommend using a build automation tool like maven or gradle to include those libraries. It gives you a platform independent project configuration and an easier dependency handling.